# Firestore security rule: How to ensure uniqueness of values in document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can the below security rule ensure uniqueness of firstName, lastName, username, and email before creating a document in profiles collection?

```
match /profiles/{document=**} {
   allow create: if request.auth.uid != null
   && (request.resource.data.firstName is string && resource.data.firstName != request.resource.data.firstName)
   && (request.resource.data.lastName is string && resource.data.firstName != request.resource.data.firstName)
  && (request.resource.data.username is string && resource.data.username != request.resource.data.username)
  && (request.resource.data.email is string && resource.data.email != request.resource.data.email)
}
```

For example, below is the data in Firestore collection profiles

```
{
   "document1":{
      "firstName":"Jek",
      "lastName":"Choo",
      "email":"jeksomething@gmail.com",
      "username":"jek"
   },
   "document2":{
      "firstName":"Cara",
      "lastName":"Choo",
      "email":"babycara@gmail.com",
      "username":"cara"
   }
}
```

I want to create the below new document, and this create access should be denied

```
{
   "document3":{
      "firstName":"Jek",
      "lastName":"Choo",
      "email":"jeksomething@gmail.com",
      "username":"jek"
   }
}
```

And I want to create the below new document, this should be allowed.

```
{
   "document4":{
      "firstName":"example",
      "lastName":"com",
      "email":"test@example.com",
      "username":"example"
   }
}
```

In conclusion, can the above firestore security rule help to ensure field value uniqueness before a document is allowed to be created?

Comment: AFAIK there is no direct API to check if collection already have a document with same values before posting  new document to cloud store collection. But there is another one method  with which you should query over all the documents of collection to check if there is already one and this can be done with [where()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) which takes three parameters: a field to filter on, a comparison operation, and a value.

Comment: Thanks but your solution is client-side validation before creating a new document. Firestore security rule is server-side validation before creating a new document. This is important.

Comment: Okey, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016426/firestore-security-rule-to-check-if-character-username-already-exists) you can read answer of `Frank van Puffelen` Engineer from Firebase on this topic. I think this cant be done with only security rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to understand what `resource` does with respect to rules that create new documents, which is the only rule you're showing here.

[`resource`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource) refers to "the (existing) document being written".  This is in contrast with `request.resource` which describes the document that doesn't yet exist, that is about to exist, if the write succeeds.

To put it another way, [in this section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation):

> The resource variable refers to the requested document, and
>   resource.data is a map of all of the fields and values stored in the
>   document.

In the case of a create, there is no *existing* document being written.  Therefore, you can assume that any matches against `resource` to fail.  Therefore, this will not ensure uniqueness.

In fact, you can not ensure uniqueness of any given document field for a create, since it's not possible in security rules to query all documents in the collection for existence for that field.

The only form of uniqueness observed by Firestore is that of the id of a document within a collection.  All fields of that document can not be constrained to be unique by security rules, and there are no indexes in Firestore that ensure uniqueness.

If you need a field to be unique, you should check *after* the document creation by using Cloud Function trigger, then delete the document if it doesn't satisfy the requirements.